# Set default values with setdefault within specific list

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting a response from API and sometimes it has an optional key called `'Selections'`. When it does not have the key I would like to have `'Selections': []` in MarketPrices like below:

```
{'MarketPrices': [{'Selections': [], '_Id': 7308747L, '_ReturnCode': 16},
                  {'_Id': 1L, '_ReturnCode': 16}],
 'ReturnStatus': {'_CallId': 7bc619bd-2805-4205-85ff-6fa5b48ea899,
                  '_Code': 0,
                  '_Description': Success},
 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 3, 21, 14, 19, 726967, tzinfo=<suds.sax.date.FixedOffsetTimezone object at 0x7f805fffed50>)}
```

I am trying to set default keys with `dict.setdefault('Selections', [])` but I get:

```
{'MarketPrices': [{'Selections': [], '_Id': 7308747L, '_ReturnCode': 16},
                  {'_Id': 1L, '_ReturnCode': 16}],
 'ReturnStatus': {'_CallId': 7bc619bd-2805-4205-85ff-6fa5b48ea899,
                  '_Code': 0,
                  '_Description': Success},
 'Selections': [],
 'Timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 3, 21, 14, 19, 726967, tzinfo=<suds.sax.date.FixedOffsetTimezone object at 0x7f805fffed50>)}
```

How can I specify that the default value should be in `'MarketPrices'`?

Comment: I removed the `'Selections'` keys from the second dictionary in the `'MarketPrices'` list and the `'ReturnStatus'` dicitonary; these obviously were not added by your code attempt.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are updating the default value of "Selections" in the parent dict,

but you need to update the value in the inner dictionary object.

```
# assuming that the super_dict object will always have "MarketPrices"
for sub_dict in super_dict['MarketPrices']:
    sub_dict.setdefault('Selections':[])
```

tip: try not to use the variable name `dict`, as it will override the builtin type constructor `dict`